# Standard Aura Component, how to view code

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I have a requirement for a Community Page.  We are using the standard Aura Compenent "Top Articles by Topic".  This component allows up to 3 columns but we only need one column.  However, when only one column is used all text is flush with the left border, it appears as if leftBorder=0.

I have tried using Salesforce Lighting Inspector, but it does not provide the code of Aura components.

I see in the below link, that the Aura project has been archived. Does this mean I will not be able to view the code of the Aura component I am looking for?

https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Does this mean I will not be able to view the code of the Aura component I am looking for?`
No, the fact that the Aura repository has been archived is completely unrelated.

You need to use your browsers developer tools to inspect/troubleshoot the issue.

The source code is equally accessible through the browsers developer tools, given that you know how to use them.

I'd suggest you take a look at [How to use Chrome's developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools)

Comment: This code would not show when using my work computer.  However on my personal it shows no problem.  I'm guessing its a browser/other extension/something. else.